# Delegation denied when try to send mail from another user's account - via api

Tags: gmail-api

In a browser, I can open my personal gmail account or I can open any delegated accounts by clicking the circle with my initial in and picking from the available delegates - no problem.
Via API however, I can get an access token for my personal account and use this to send mail from my own account. If I try to send from the delegated account then I get the error.

So I have a token for my personal account eg **me@gmail.com**
and post to https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/**delegator@gmail.com**/drafts

because me@gmail.com has been delegated to by delagator@gmail.com I would expect the api call to work with my access token - in the same way as when I am signed in to my account in a browser then I can then open the delegator account without having to provide credentials again.

'{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Delegation denied for me@gmail.com","errors":[{"message":"Delegation denied for me@gmail.com","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}'

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a specific email address in the request. Maybe try by with userId="me".

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do you mean in the URL eg https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts  ?

Comment: Yes, I think that may work.

Comment: Using "me" works if I have an access token from my account and the mail is sent from my account. But I want to send from another account that I have been delegated to but using my account access token.